# ALternative to eval for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string "Mymodel::FirstClass" stored in db and i need to call Mymodel::FirstClass (out from string).
How to do this without using eval(string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you require Active Record, you can use constantize (see [here](https://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize))

So for example, something like this:

```
require "active_record"

"Mymodel::FirstClass".constantize
=> Mymodel::FirstClass
```

Or you can use `const_get`

```
Kernel.const_get("Mymodel::FirstClass")
=> MyModel::FirstClass
```

Comment: Small correction:`constantize` is in `ActiveSupport`, not `ActiveRecord`. Regardless though, the fact that OP tagged this question as `ruby-on-rails` should mean they have it available in their project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `constantize` as Stellenerger suggested. Or when the string might include a class names that might not exists then you might want to use [`safe_constantize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-safe_constantize) which simply returns `nil` then the constant was not found instead of raising an exception:

```
"Mymodel::FirstClass".safe_constantize
#=> Mymodel::FirstClass

"NonExistingClass".safe_constantize
#=> nil
```

Comment: I didn't know that method, but its name seems a bit misleading. Is it is more "safe" to rescue the exceptions and keep going?